# Posabsolute's jQuery Validation-Engine and CkEditor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, jquery-validation-engine

I have searched the site (and Google) and cannot find a working solution for my problem.

I'm using Posabsolute's Validation-Engine, and it is working just fine.  Except for my problem children - my CKeditor formatted textareas.

I know that I need to evaluate the textarea using `CKEditor.instances.textareaid.updateElement()`, but can't get it to work.

Anyone have any hints/solutions on how to work this?  Perhaps there is a setting in the validationEngine.js that I need to override?

Any pointers will be most welcome :)

Comment: You may have to update a hidden input with the CKEditor data before validation.

Answer (score 4):

```
jQuery(function()
{
    CKEDITOR.replace("editor_id",
    {
        width:"750px",
        height:"300px",
        on:
        {
            instanceReady: function(ev)
            { 
                jQuery("#editor_id").css({display:"block",visibility:"hidden",position:"absolute"});
                this.document.on("keyup", CK_jQ);
                this.document.on("paste", CK_jQ);
            }
        }
    });
});

function CK_jQ()
{
    CKEDITOR.tools.setTimeout( function()
    { 
        jQuery("#editor_id").val(CKEDITOR.instances.editor_id.getData()); 
    }, 0);
}

function validateFrm()
{
    if(JQObj('#'+frmID).validationEngine('validate'))
    {
        return true;
    } 
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

//your html is like below

form method="post" name="formId" id="formId" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateFrm('formId');"

Answer (score 2):

I've done it like so:

```
         if(typeof CKEDITOR !== 'undefined'){
               for(var i in CKEDITOR.instances){ //editors
                $("form textarea[name="+CKEDITOR.instances[i].name+"]").addClass("validate[required]");
                $("form textarea[name="+CKEDITOR.instances[i].name+"]").attr("data-prompt-position", 'bottomLeft:400,0');
               }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that ValidationEngine only validates visible fields and CKeditor hides the original textarea, or div, with `visibility: hidden; display: none;` inline styling.
As you have found out this code `CKEditor.instances.textareaId.updateElement()` is needed to transfer the content of the editor area back to the original element, but more needs to be done.

You also need to make the original element visible again, and using `$('#textareaId').toggle()` or `$('#textareaId').show()` does this. Now you can validate all your fields using this:

```
$('#formId').validationEngine('validate');
```

Now another issue arises, the error prompt is not near the editor area, but at the original element because of `visibility: hidden`, but that is not a problem. We simply hide the original element again, with `$('#textareaId').toggle()` or `$('#textareaId').hide()`, to make the prompt align with the editor.

## Complete code

This code is using CKEditor v4 and validationEngine v2.5.

```
<form id="yourFormId" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
<textarea id="textareaId" class="ckeditor"></textarea>
</form>
<script>
function validate(form) {
    CKEDITOR.instances.textareaId.updateElement();
    $('#textareaId').toggle();
    validated = $(form).validationEngine('validate');
    $('#textareaId').toggle();

    return validated;
}
</script>
```

You may want to add a loop if you got multiple editor elements.
The only *downside* with this code is the hardcoded original elementId(s).

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use some CSS tricks instead.
I would use this styles for the textarea

```
.wysiwyg-editor{
    visibility: hidden !important;
    display: block !important;
    height: 0px;
}
```

I think this is a cleaner solution.